# How to append after selection

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to append some code after my current selection, lets say I have this:

<div id="test">

</div>

and want to append <br /> after closing div, like this

<div id="test">

</div>

<br />

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method:

```
$( '#test' ).after ( '<br/>' );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#test').after('<br />');
```

That what you are after?

Comment: I removed my vote after you edited it. It was wrong, so I down voted :)

Comment: how come its still on a "-1" !?